# Why ThreadPool doesn't move next after a TimeoutError

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, threadpool

My goal:

- To go through a list of websites to check them using Requests. This is being done in `apply_job`.

My problem:

- When `job_pool.next` is called, a few websites are in error and instead of giving an error, they just stand there and don't even give a `TimeoutError`. That's why I am using a timeout in the `next` function with 10s of timeout. This timeout works well but when the `TimeoutError` exception arises, the `next` function the following times keep raising the exception even though the next websites are good. It seems to me that it doesn't move to the next item and just loop over the same one.
- I tried with `imap` and `imap_unordered`, no difference in that.

My code here:

```
   def run_check(websites):
        """ Run check on the given websites """
        import multiprocessing
        from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

        pool = ThreadPool(processes=JOB_POOL_SIZE)

        try:
            job_pool = pool.imap_unordered(apply_job, websites)

            try:
                while True:
                    try:
                        res = job_pool.next(10)
                    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                        logging.error("Timeout Error")
                        res = 'No Res'

                    csv_callback(res)

            except StopIteration:
                pass

            pool.terminate()
        except Exception, e:
            logging.error("Run_check Error: %s"%e)
            raise
```

I use `res = requests.get(url, timeout=10)` to check the websites. This timeout doesn't work for this issue.

To test, here are the websites that makes the problem (not every time but very often): http://www.kddecorators.netfirms.com, http://www.railcar.netfirms.com.

I can't figure out what is different with these websites but my guess is that they keep sending a byte once in a while so it isn't considered as a real timeout even though they are unusable.

If anyone has an idea, it would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on that one for a few days now. I even tried `future` and `async` but they don't raise the exception which I need.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue, I used `eventlet` and its `Timeout` function.

```
def apply_job(account_info):
    """ Job for the Thread """
    try:
        account_id = account_info['id']
        account_website = account_info['website']
        url = account_website
        result = "ERROR: GreenPool Timeout"
        with Timeout(TIMEOUT*2, False):
            url, result = tpool.execute(website.try_url, account_website)

        return (account_id, account_website, url, result)

    except Exception, e:
        logging.error("Apply_job Error: %s"%e)

def start_db(res):
    update_db(res)
    csv_file.csv_callback(res)

def spawn_callback(result):
    res = result.wait()
    tpool.execute(start_db, res)

def run_check(websites):
    """ Run check on the given websites """
    print str(len(websites)) + " items found\n"

    pool = eventlet.GreenPool(100)
    for i, account_website in enumerate(websites):
        res = pool.spawn(apply_job, account_website)
        res.link(spawn_callback)

    pool.waitall()
```

This solution works well because it times-out over the whole execution of the function `website.try_url` in the command `url, result = tpool.execute(website.try_url, account_website)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition that passing a timeout to `next` would abort the job is wrong. It just aborts waiting, but the particular job keeps running. The next time you wait, you do wait for the same job. To achieve a timeout on the actual jobs you should look at the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts). Note that there is no reliable way to terminate another thread. So if you absolutely cannot make your jobs terminate within a reasonable time frame, you can switch to a process based pool and forcefully terminate the processes (e.g. using `signal.alarm`).